# Search a specific number in a sum of sublist Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to know how to search a number, for instance T, exists if we addition the elements of a list.
For exemple, if I have a list L=[1,5,-2,6] and T= 3, T exists.

The list hits 20 to 30 elements, any ideas ?

Comment: This is a nice interview task, which can be solved with prefix sums and little bit of dynamic programming. :)

Comment: -4 oO, well I guess i'll be looking on my own. Thx for replying anyway :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Didn't know this problem was popular (nothing on stackoverflow), thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if someone wants to know one day here's what I found :

```
final nt TAB_SIZE = 30;

int[] tab = new int[TAB_SIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < TAB_SIZE; i++){
    tab[i] = i;
}
int T = -1;
int n = tab.length;

if (isSubsetSum(tab, n, T))
    System.out.println("Found");
else
    System.out.println("Not found");


public boolean isSubsetSum(int tab[], int n, int T){
    if (T == 0)
        return true;
    if (n == 0) //So T !=0
        return false;
        //If the last element is higher, we ignore it
    if (tab[n-1] > T)
        return isSubsetSum(tab, n-1, T);

    //Otherwise, looking if the sum can be obtain bith adding ou excluding the last element
    return isSubsetSum(tab, n-1, T) || isSubsetSum(tab, n-1, T-tab[n-1]);
}
```

This algorithm is really fast but will only works with positive values